# jquery not getting data from outputText field

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

ok, I have a VF page. and some inputField as well as outputText, and I wanted to do some front end calculation on these data while a button is clicked. on the outputText, for example I have:

```
<apex:outputText id="processor_name" value="{!ProcessorName}" label="Processor" />
```

here is the button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="executeCalculation()">Calculate</button>
```

And here is the jquery

```
function executeCalculation(){  
                alert($j("[id$='num_locations']").val());  
}
```

the outputText field is displaying data from database just fine.

the alert message is just blank, not showing anything. 
if I change the script to

```
function executeCalculation(){  
        $j("[id$='num_locations']").hide();  
}
```

the field will hide just fine. I'm not sure why I can't get the data to display in the alert.

Comment: Please try to select the most appropriate tags and avoid using general tags. This will help get the right people to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jQuery `.val()` method is used to retrieve the value of an input element. You are attempting to use it to get the value from a non-input element which is why you are getting a null result.

Try using either of the two methods available for retrieving the contents of matched elements as text or html. (Usage depends on your specific need)

http://api.jquery.com/text/

```
function executeCalculation() {
    alert($j("[id$='num_locations']").text());
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
function executeCalculation() {
    alert($j("[id$='num_locations']").html());
}
```

Comment: wow, didn't think about it at all. works perfect now. thanks so much